# Syntax Highlight line above matched pattern

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting

I am looking for a way to highlight text on the line above a matched pattern. For example, my text may appear like this:

```
Some text
---------
```

What I want is to match on the underline dashes and then highlight the 'Some text' based on that. I can match the dashes and highlight them by matching any set of three dashes like this:

```
syn match dashes "\v^\-\-\-.*$"
```

But I am not sure how to also highlight the line above. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward using the `\zs` and `\ze` atoms. I would do this:

```
syn match preDashes ".*\n\ze---"
```

Using the `\ze` atom here makes it so the matched text is *only* what matches before the `\ze`, but the whole pattern still must match.

As for style, I'd would *highly* recommend dropping the `\v` setting. In general, it's only useful when it makes the whole regex shorter or more readable. Which is easier to understand at first glance?

```
\v^\-\-\-.*$
^---.*$
```

For what it's worth, since `.*` is greedy, it will match as much text as possible, so the EOL (`$`) is not needed either. Putting all of this together, I would recommend:

```
syn match dashes "^---.*"
syn match preDashes ".*\n\ze---"
```

(Although I'm sure you can come up with a better name than *preDashes*)

Comment: Thanks! I am new to this and now realize that I was making it much more difficult than I needed to. This was a great answer!

Comment: @jgp I'm glad you found it useful!

Comment: THAT should be in a HOWTO page of its own somewhere in the Vim doc.